# Count occurance of multiple items for a specific master item in 2D array using python

Tags: python, list, count

I have 2D lists with each row containing COMMON_NAME entries and additional information. I want to find sum of how many MYFR elements belong to each COMMON_NAME.

```
For example, this is my list 
[['SOME TEXT', 'COMMON_NAME1', None, 'CHOC', 'MYFR01'],
['SOME TEXT2', 'COMMON_NAME1', None, 'ABC',  'MYFR02'], 
['SOME TEXT3', 'COMMON_NAME1', None, 'XYZ',  'MYFR03'],
['SOME TEXT4', 'COMMON_NAME2', None, 'XYZ',  'STRAWBERRY'],
['SOME TEXT5', 'COMMON_NAME2', None, 'XYZ',  'MYFR01'],
['SOME TEXT6', 'COMMON_NAME2', None, 'XYZ',  'MYFR02'],
['SOME TEXT7', 'COMMON_NAME2', None, 'XYZ',  'APPLE']
```

For every COMMOM_NAME, I want to find the sum of occurances if they are in {'MYFR01', 'MYFR02', 'MYFR03'}

Such that in this example I want to get COMMON_NAME1 = 3 and COMMON_NAME2 = 2

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution with `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> data = [['SOME TEXT', 'COMMON_NAME1', None, 'CHOC', 'MYFR01'],
... ['SOME TEXT2', 'COMMON_NAME1', None, 'ABC',  'MYFR02'], 
... ['SOME TEXT3', 'COMMON_NAME1', None, 'XYZ',  'MYFR03'],
... ['SOME TEXT4', 'COMMON_NAME2', None, 'XYZ',  'STRAWBERRY'],
... ['SOME TEXT5', 'COMMON_NAME2', None, 'XYZ',  'MYFR01'],
... ['SOME TEXT6', 'COMMON_NAME2', None, 'XYZ',  'MYFR02'],
... ['SOME TEXT7', 'COMMON_NAME2', None, 'XYZ',  'APPLE']]

>>> c = Counter(i[1] for i in data if i[-1].startswith('MYFR'))
>>> c
Counter({'COMMON_NAME1': 3, 'COMMON_NAME2': 2})
```

This assumes that your target choices will always start with `MYFR`.  Reading your question a bit more closely, you could also use:

```
>>> tgt = {'MYFR01', 'MYFR02', 'MYFR03'}
>>> c = Counter(i[1] for i in data if i[-1] in tgt)
>>> c
Counter({'COMMON_NAME1': 3, 'COMMON_NAME2': 2})
```

The nice thing about [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (a subclass of `dict`) is that it can accept a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).  This means you don't need to materialize the "filtered" items into some intermediate data structure such as a list.

Comment: Running both these solutions give Counter() value with len = 0 on my python 3.7. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Nevermind, it was just the offset value incorrect. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `pandas` for this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['text', 'cname', 'none', 'code', 'name'])

         text         cname  none  code        name
0   SOME TEXT  COMMON_NAME1  None  CHOC      MYFR01
1  SOME TEXT2  COMMON_NAME1  None   ABC      MYFR02
2  SOME TEXT3  COMMON_NAME1  None   XYZ      MYFR03
3  SOME TEXT4  COMMON_NAME2  None   XYZ  STRAWBERRY
4  SOME TEXT5  COMMON_NAME2  None   XYZ      MYFR01
5  SOME TEXT6  COMMON_NAME2  None   XYZ      MYFR02
6  SOME TEXT7  COMMON_NAME2  None   XYZ       APPLE


df.loc[df['name'].str.contains('MYFR'), ['name', 'cname']] \
  .groupby('cname', as_index=False) \
  .count()

          cname  name
0  COMMON_NAME1     3
1  COMMON_NAME2     2
```

Additionally we can use itertools:

```
from itertools import groupby

second = itemgetter(1)
last = itemgetter(-1)

for k, v in groupby(data, key=second):
    print(k, len([last(i) for i in v if last(i).startswith('MYFR')]))

COMMON_NAME1 3
COMMON_NAME2 2
```

The only caveat here is that the data has to be sorted first.

Answer (score 0):

We'll keep a dictionary mapping `COMMON_NAME` values to sets of `MYFR` values, then measure the size of those sets at the end.  This determines the number of unique `MYFR` elements for each `COMMON_NAME`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)

for first, common_name, *others, last in my_list:
    if common_name.startswith("COMMON_NAME"):  # Maybe unneccessary
        if last.startswith("MYFR"):
            d[common_name].add(last)

d = {k: len(v) for k, v in d.items()}
# {'COMMON_NAME1': 3, 'COMMON_NAME2': 2}
```